# Jasmine: Test that returned promise is a concrete exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I have a method in my **node.js** server, that returns a Promise - throws a custom Exception (`UserNotAuthenticatedError`) - and I want to write a test to make sure that this Exception is thrown whenever it has to.

The method is the following:

```
export function changePassword(userId, oldPass, newPass) {
  var query = User.findById(userId);
  return query.exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.authenticate(oldPass)) {
        user.password = newPass;
        return user.save();
      } else {
        // I want to test that this Exception is thrown
        throw new UserNotAuthenticatedError();
      }
    });
}
```

I've tried writing the test, and this is what I have so far:

```
describe('#changePassword', function() {
    it('should throw a UserNotAuthenticatedError when passing wrong password', function() {
      var userId = user._id;
      var wrongPwd = 'wrongpassword';
      var newPwd = 'new password';
      // so far the following only tells me that the Promise was rejected, but
      // I WANT TO TEST THAT THE REJECTION WAS DUE TO A 'UserNotAuthenticatedError'
      UserService.changePassword(userId, wrongPwd, newPwd).should.be.rejected;
    });
  });
```

I have accomplished checking that the promise returned was rejected, but I also want to be more specific and check that the returned promise is a `UserNotAuthenticatedError`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up finding a much nicer way to solve it:

```
it('should throw a UserNotAuthenticatedError when passing wrong password', function() {
  var userId = user._id;
  var wrongPwd = 'wrongpassword';
  var newPwd = 'new password';

  var promise = UserService.changePassword(userId, wrongPwd, newPwd);
  return promise.should.be.rejectedWith(UserNotAuthenticatedError);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just use a `promise.catch(function(error){})` and inspect the `error` variable to make sure it's the right type of error?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are better ways to handle this than the one I propose. This one should work nevertheless.

```
var promise = UserService.changePassword(userId, wrongPwd, newPwd);
var error = null;
promise.should.be.rejected;
promise.then(function(){}, function(err){
    expect(err).toEqual(jasmine.any(UserNotAuthenticatedError));
    done();
});
```

Where done is function which could be passed as parameter to the it method. It specifies that it is asynchronous test.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the second argument to `.then` instead of the more idiomatic `.catch`?